# Handling custom component checkboxes with Field as in Formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, state, formik

I've been stuck for past couple of hours trying to figure out how to handle a form with a custom checkbox component in [formik](/questions/tagged/formik). I'm passing it via the `<Formik as >`introduced in Formik 2.0

Issue arises with `input type='checkbox'` as I can't just directly pass `true` or `false` values to it.

> Now I'm posting the solution which I am aware is a bad implementation.
>   I didn't really find a way to properly pass values from the component,
>   so I wanted to hande it as a separate state in the component as the
>   checkbox will take care of its own state.

My custom input component is structured the following way

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyledSwitch, Wrapper } from './Switch.styled';

type Props = {
  value: boolean;
  displayOptions?: boolean;
  optionTrue?: string;
  optionFalse?: string;
};

const Switch: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const { value, optionTrue = 'on', optionFalse = 'off', displayOptions = false } = props;
  const [switchVal, setSwitchVal] = useState<boolean>(value);

  const handleSwitchChange = (): void => setSwitchVal(!switchVal);

  return (
    <Wrapper styledVal={switchVal}>
      <StyledSwitch type="checkbox" checked={switchVal} onChange={handleSwitchChange} />
      {displayOptions && (switchVal ? optionTrue : optionFalse)}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Switch;
```

The `./Switch.styled` utilizes [styled-components](/questions/tagged/styled-components) but they are not relevant to this question. Imagine them simply as an `<input>` and `<div>` respectively

Now here's the component which handles the switch

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import Switch from '../../../components/forms/Switch';

const QuizMenu: React.FC = () => {
  const [isMultipleChoice, setIsMultipleChoice] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const sleep = (ms: number): Promise<number> => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ isMultipleChoice: 'false', password: '' }}
      onSubmit={async (values): Promise<boolean> => {
        await sleep(1000);
        JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
        return true;
      }}
    >
      {
        (): any => ( // to be replaced with formik destruct, but dont want eslint problems before implementation
          <Form>
            <div>
              <Field as={Switch} onClick={setIsMultipleChoice(!isMultipleChoice)} value={isMultipleChoice === true} name="isMultipleChoice" displayOptions />
              { isMultipleChoice }
            </div>
          </Form>
        )
      }
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default QuizMenu
```

;

Which yields the following error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

I also tried editing the `value` to string as per `input type='checkboxed'`but I can't really find a way to handle it. If you handle it in a separate `handleChange()` function you get rid of the error, but then the `state` doesn't update for some reason.

What would be the proper way of handling this?